# Problem - 'dispatch' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c#, dispatch, azure-bot-service

When I tried to create `dispatch-Model` for my bot., I am getting following error - `'dispatch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`Before using `dispatch` command, I installed `botdispatch` using `npm install -g botdispatch`. But still I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your NPM folder to see if there is anything with dispatch there? Assuming you're on Windows, this is typically in AppData\Roaming\npm.

PowerShell:

```
dir $home\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

CMD:

```
dir %homepath%\AppData\Roaming\npm.
```

If dispatch (dispatch.cmd) is there, then it might be a pathing issue. Check  your path variables to make sure that that path is there:

CMD:

```
echo %path%
```

PowerShell:

```
($env:path).Split(';')
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have `dispatch.cmd` file. By running `cmd` as `administrator` and than reinstalling `botdispatch` solved my problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is pathing issue means !!! and how you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

So I was having this same issue, it turns out I needed to add the path of the NPM folder C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm to my path for Powershell7.

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm"
```

Where xxxxxx is your userid.  After adding this command to Powershell the npm modules began to work.

If you do not see this path by running this command below, then you need to add it with the one above.

```
($env:path).Split(';')
```

All of these should be ran inside of a PS7 window, I ran them with Administrator rights when I launched the Powershell 7 window.